# Is Azure table or NoSQL in general not so good when updating data

Tags: nosql, azure-table-storage

I have only looked in Azure table, but it may well apply for other NoSQL databases as well.
If I have an entity consisting of these following properties

> First name - Last name - Hometown - Country

In Azure table there is no concept of relations therefore if I have thousands of data, and I want to change all entities that has 'Canada' in it, to some other country. Then in this scenario there is a possibility it has to go through thousands of data to find entities with 'Canada' and change it to something else.

I wonder, is the benefit of NoSQL only if you have data that is static and not changed after you have written it? Or could this problem be solved for NoSQLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of NoSQL data stores the advantages are different from SQL databases. Things like scalability or availability can be better in a NoSQL database like Azure table, but there are tradeoffs. For example you are generally unable to efficiently query any part of a record, only the keys.

In designing your schema for Azure Table you have to consider the use cases of your data layer and let that dictate the schema. In this example, if I thought I would have to update all records in a given country, I would make that part of the partition or row key. That way your query to get all data in a given country is fast and can be updated quickly.

Comment: In other word unless you can partition in such way, instead the country will be a property of the table. Then updating each entity will be really inefficient? I've looked into an approach where I have another table containing the countries. Which I then uses primary key and foreign key to refer them. It would require an extra query though since I cannot use joins.

Comment: Right, unless you make the country part of one of your keys, you'll have to scan each record to find all records that contain that country to update them.

You can do the external table approach, but it does require a second query to pull the list of countries. You could also cache that list in memory since it should remain relatively static.